# MySQL Index: 1 keyname multiple columns OR 1 keyname per column?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am trying to speed up my MySQL tables by using indices. When I add an index using PHPmyadmin, there are 2 columns, keyname and column. I have a few table columns that I want indexed.

**Problem:** What is the difference between having 1 keyname per column, and 1 keyname for all the columns I want indexed? I notice that using 1 keyname for all the indexed columns work the best. What is happening?

The first column in the keyname with multiple columns is the first column that appears in my MySQL query. I think this has something to do with using 1 keyword multiple columns, but I'm not sure why this is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Multi-column indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) ("1 keyname for all the columns") are different than [single-column indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/column-indexes.html) for each column. It all depends on your queries.

If you're querying by multiple columns frequently, you want to index that combination. For example if you query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE (age > 18 AND name = "Johnnie Walker")
```

you need to add the index on two columns: (age,name)

Comment: Am I right to say that each keyname creates a different index, and each database query uses only 1 of the many indices, and that there are as many index as there are keynames?

Comment: @Nyxynyx: Yes on your first assumption. No on your second assumption. The query engine is free to use as many indexes as it needs to optimize a query. Yes on your third assumptions.

Comment: @Asaph: Thanks! Any idea why is an index referred to as a `keyname` in PHPmyadmin?

Comment: If there are 2 common queries on the table with 20 cols, the first queries 5 columns, and the 2nd queries 6-8 columns, should I have 2 indices where one has 5 cols and the other have 8 cols? I'm guessing when the 2nd query occurs, it will use the index with 8 cols

Comment: For that query, I don't think you want a multi-column index on "age,column".  But maybe you are not suggesting that.  A two-column index consisting of age,name (in that order) would not be that useful for resolving the "name" part of the WHERE clause.  On the other hand, if it were "name,age" (name as the first column in the index), then it could be used to optimize that query very well (although it depends on the database engine ... I'm only assuming things about the optimization of this in mysql).  The query plan would help answer that.

Comment: @Nyxynyx: In MySQL syntax, `INDEX` and `KEY` as the same. Perhaps that's why PHPMYAdmin uses the "keyname". It's the name of the key (index).